# Suppose $R_{1} , R_{2}$ are transitive relations on a set A. Will $R_{1} \cup R_{2}$ also be transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Suppose  $R_{1} , R_{2}$ are transitive and let $(x,z)\in R_{1}\circ R_{1}\subseteq R_{1}$ and $(x,z)\in R_{2}\circ R_{2}\subseteq R_{2}$.

Since we have $R_{1} \cup R_{2}$ , consider the case $(x,z)\in R_{1} \land (x,z)\notin R_{2}$. By the initial assumptions, this would lead to a contradiction. A similar contradiction arises when we consider the case $(x,z)\in R_{2} \land (x,z)\notin R_{1}$. The only case that would satisfy the initial assumtions is when $(x,z)\in R_{2} \land (x,z)\in R_{1}$ Therefore $R_{1} \cup R_{2}$ is not transitive. And infact, we have also shown that $R_{1} \cap R_{2}$ is transitive under the same assumptions.

My question is, was it right for me to only consider arbitrary elements of a certain form that are in or not in the union? I reasoned that these elements are the only important ones when considering whether or not a set is transitive by the given definition of a set not being transitive $\exists x,y,x \in A \left[ (x,y),(y,z)\in R \land (x,z)\notin R \right]$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the set $S=\{a,b,c\}$ and the relations $R_1$ and $R_2$ on $S$ defined by $R_1=\{(a,b)\}$ and $R_2=\{(b,c)\}$. Both $R_1$ and $R_2$ are transitive, but $R_1 \cup R_2$ is not.

A specific, concrete example is
$$\begin{eqnarray}
S&=&\{\mbox{John Adams}, \mbox{John F. Kennedy}, \mbox{Robert F. Kennedy}\}, \\
R_1&\mbox{is}&\mbox{shares-his-given-name-with}, \mbox{and} \\
R_2&\mbox{is}&\mbox{shares-his-family-name-with},
\end{eqnarray}$$
so $R_1 \cup R_2$ is shares-his-given-or-family-name-with.